# How to install Nginx by Ansible on FreeBSD?

Tags: nginx, ansible

I try to install Nginx with Ansible on FreeBSD 10. But I have a this problem. 
When I tried to install Nginx from Ansible playbook like this

```
- name: nginx install
  portinstall: name=nginx state=present
```

I got this error, because nginx installed without HTTP_REALIP module.

> "nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
>   nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "set_real_ip_from"

And When I tried to install like this

```
- name: Install nginx
  shell: "cd /usr/ports/www/nginx &&make HTTP_REALIP=on BATCH=yes install clean"
```

I got same error too, because HTTP_REALIP module not be installed anyway.

How to install Nginx by Ansible with HTTP_REALIP module?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
- name: install nginx
  become: yes
  pkgng:
    name: nginx
    state: present
```

Comment: I tried, but I got 
"ERROR: state is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
"

Comment: I installed Nginx 
- name: install nginx become=yes
  pkgng: name=nginx state=present

But REALIP module not included too